# `git diff --submodule=diff` doesn't show diff in submodule that points to a different repository

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-diff

As an example of my problem, consider [ssh2-rs repo](https://github.com/alexcrichton/ssh2-rs) has a submodule at the path `libssh2-sys/libssh2` that points to [libssh2 repo](https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2). Now, within `ssh2-rs@0.2.19` [`d2ef03f`] and `ssh2-rs@0.2.20`[`1fcf8d3`], the reference pointer to the submodule was updated. Now when I run `git diff --submodule=diff d2ef03f..1fcf8d3`< i expect the diff to show me the code changes within the submodule too, but it does not. For example, the [GitHub compare](https://github.com/alexcrichton/ssh2-rs/compare/libssh2-sys-0.2.19...libssh2-sys-0.2.20) page shows a link to the diff for the files within the submodule. Ideally, I would want a single `diff` command to show all the code changes between two commits, including changes within the submodule files in the case where the submodule reference pointer was updated. Is that doable? How can I achieve that?

Comment: I just tried `git diff --submodule=diff d2ef03f..1fcf8d3` and it did show me the actual code  changes within libssh2, in diff format.

Comment: you cloned the repo by `git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/alexcrichton/ssh2-rs`? And then run the diff command? Did you do anything else?

Comment: I cloned ssh2-rs first, then went in and did `git submodule init; git submodule update`.  Nothing else.

Comment: Followup question: `git diff --submodule=diff d2ef03f..1fcf8d3 -- libssh2-sys/libssh2/src/agent.c` does this command show you anything?

Comment: Returns `Submodule libssh2-sys/libssh2 6da9d78...cfe0bf6 (commits not present)`.

Comment: If I do `git diff --submodule=diff d2ef03f..1fcf8d3 -- libssh2-sys/libssh2`, it shows me `Submodule libssh2-sys/libssh2 6da9d78...cfe0bf6 (commits not present)`. I did the init and update thing, but no difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241546/discussion-between-nasif-imtiaz-ohi-and-jingx).

Answer (score 0):

I had to `git submodule init; git submodule update` at both the commit points where I wanted the diff (`d2ef03f..1fcf8d3` in the example). Apparently, that enables my repo to fetch updates from the old reference pointers from the submodule remote in order to have the corresponding commits of the remote repository available within my repo and git to show me the diff.